# How to pass values from a selected table row to my backend

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, sqlalchemy

In my `index.html` page I have a table row:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                <td hidden="" class="sorting_1">6</td>
                <td>example_name</td>
                <td>example_phone</td>
                <td>example_email</td>
              </tr>
```

The table in index.html is rendered using bootstrap 4 and MDBootstrap.

after selecting the row in the browser, the `<tr>` class changes its state to `tr-color-selected`:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd tr-color-selected" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                <td hidden="" class="sorting_1">6</td>
                <td>example_name</td>
                <td>example_phone</td>
                <td>example_email</td>
              </tr>
```

how can I pass the values of `example_name, example_phone, example_email` from the selected table row to my controller `views.py`? I am using Flask and SQLAlchemy in my backend.

---

**Edit #1 - server-side javascript code**

I am using MDBootstrap Modal Editor (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/plugins/table-editor/)to render my datatable:

```
<script>
  $('#persons_table').mdbEditor({
  modalEditor: true,
  headerLength: 6,
  });
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
</script>
```

This is my code that generates the table:

```
<!-- table -->
        <table id="persons_table" class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th hidden class="th-sm">ID
              </th>
              <th class="th-sm">example_name
              </th>
              <th class="th-sm">example_phone
              </th>
              <th class="th-sm">example_email
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {% for row in persons %}
              <tr>
                <td hidden>{{row.id}}</td>
                <td>{{row.example_name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.example_phone}}</td>
                <td>{{row.example_email}}</td>
              </tr>
            {%- endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to set up a form and make an HTTP request via JavaScript. At least. Tell us more about your JS code please.

Comment: I've added some code, however I am not sure how it will help with my question. JS from a script running in the background (from MDBootstrap) is helping me with the rendering and selection of the table row and chaning of the <tr> class. But for passing the values to my flask controller I dont have any specific JS yet. Usually I am getting values using a request.form['value'] in my controller.